# Old Chats disappearing from Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Old Chats are disappearing from my Chat-Overview in Whatsapp. I did not delete them, and they are still there: When I search for a contact and then click on them, I can see all the messages of the chat, but nevertheless this chat is missing from the Chat-Overview.

Now my problem is: One of my contacts has quit whatsapp over a year ago, so their account is not active anymore. And therefore I do not see them in my contacts-list. If only I could click (or tap) on that contact, then all the messages would be there again, I am quite sure.

But how can I open this chat, which is not visible in the chat-overview anymore and does not have a valid contact attachted to it?

Comment: As suggested bellow, try search a specific word you wrote to them (your inactive contact) or write their name in the search bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, that you archived your chats. To find your archived chats, scroll down to the bottom of main WhatsApp page and you'll see the archive tab. Open it and your chats should all be there. Long press on any of them and move them back.

You can also try searching for a word that you might have written to a contact. For example, if you search for the word "thanks" in WhatsApps main search bar, that should bring up any chat that the word was written in.

Comment: You can also search for your friends chat by entering his old number in the main search bar

Comment: Unfortunatly the chat is not archived, I checked. And I did not delete it either. I also restored an old backup into whatsapp. At the time of the backup the chat was definetly there. Restoring the backup did reset all chats to their respective state at the time, but the chat in question remained invisible.

Comment: entering the old number in the search bar does not yield any results for that specific contact

Comment: I'm understanding from your comment that now all chats are back to normal, besides that one friends chat.

Comment: no, backing up to 3 months before just deleted the messages of the last three months (as expected), but did not change anything else. One chat is still only accessible over the contacts-tab, and that one special chat with the inactive contact is still not visible anywhere

Comment: Here's a few things to try: 1. search a word that you might have written to him. For example if you search the word 'thanks' in WhatsApp, it will show all chats that you ever write that word to. 2. If you were in a group with him, go into that group and look for a post from that contact, click on the phone number, and it should open the chat with that contact. If none work, i have a few more suggestions

Comment: searching for the word I had written in the chat did the trick! I did find the chat!!! You should definetly update your answer so that everyone else will be able to find your solution! I am voting up your answer now :-)

Comment: Great! I'm still perplexed as to why some chats are hidden. If you open one of the "hidden" chats is there anything in the menu that would be similar to an "un-hide" option?